# How to fetch file id from file names in pyspark column

Tags: pyspark

I have a big pyspark dataframe like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|filename                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|file:///Users/downloads/201709_PO.dat|
|file:///Users/downloads/201723_PO.dat|
```

I want to get a new column with the id which is the first 5 digit of the filename.

Output I want:

```
+-------------------------------------|-------|
|filename                             | id    |
+-------------------------------------|-------|
|file:///Users/downloads/201709_PO.dat|201709 |
|file:///Users/downloads/201723_PO.dat|201723 |
```

How can I achieve this in efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `regexp_extract` function.

```
df = df.withColumn('id', F.regexp_extract('filename', '([0-9]{6})', 1))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always 6 digits, you can use `substring`.

```
df = df.withColumn('id', substring(substring_index(df.filename, '/', -1), 0, 6))
```

The middle part `substring_index(df.filename, '/', -1)` is to take a filename out of full path.
Then use `substring(filename, 0, 6)` to take first 6 characters out from the filename.

If you want to extract any characters before "_", you can use `substring_index` twice.

```
df = df.withColumn('id', substring_index(substring_index(df.filename, '/', -1), '_', 1))
```